# capistrano ignores specific branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano

in config/deploy.rb file, the following code is there already

```
set :branch, 'LE-68'
```

Even after this following code is executed. LE-68 is anyways cloned, however deploy branch is checked out by capistrano. I don't want this behaviour to happen.

```
executing "git clone -q -b LE-68 git@github.com:bac/wonderla.git /home/bac/wonderla/releases/20131120125828 && cd /home/bac/wonderla/releases/20131120125828 && git checkout -q -b deploy 9db18077e1a4e7830f123eb6b03f5cd17cad5e3a && (echo 9db18077e1a4e7830f123eb6b03f5cd17cad5e3a > /home/bac/wonderla/releases/20131120125828/REVISION)"
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Capistrano version I am using is 2.15.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how Capistrano works. The cached copy is switched to the reference defined in `LE-86`, and that is then cloned into the release directory.

There is no way around it.